# Pymodbus: can i get a client object from ModbusClientFactory (as with protocol.ClientCreator)

Tags: python, twisted, modbus

I used twisted.internet.protocol.ClientCreator with success to get an "client" object as a result from a deferred callback:

```
deferred = protocol.ClientCreator( reactor, ModbusClientProtocol ).connectTCP( "localhost", 502 )
```

I want to refactor my code to use the twisted.internet.protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory instead.
As i understand, pymodbus.client.async.ModbusClientFactory already inherits from ReconnectingClientFactory.
Is there a way to get an client object like the one from ClientCreator after calling:

```
reactor.connectTCP( "localhost", 502, ModbusClientFactory() )
```

I want to perform cyclic read-holding-register-requests via Modbus and not have to worry about reconnecting after lost connections myself.
Do I have to subclass the ModbusClientFactory? If so, could someone post a short example that shows how to perform read_holding_registers requests in a class method?

Answer (score 1):

If you used [endpoints](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/endpoints.html) instead of reactor methods, you could construct an appropriate endpoint around `ModbusClientFactory` and get a `Deferred` that fired with its protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, the twistes docu states: _..a few features (such as automatic reconnection) have not been re-implemented with endpoints yet.._ [link](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html#clientfactory)

Comment: `ClientCreator` doesn't implement automatic reconnecting either - that's `ReconnectingClientFactory` :).  However, you can easily enough implement reconnection by watching for `connectionLost` in your `Protocol`.

Comment: If you're interested in tracking progress on that particular deficiency, though, please see here: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4735